# Singleton Object in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton

I am learning PHP and trying to understand Singleton Object but can't really understand what does it actually means?

If I create a Singleton Object, is it one object for all the clients or every client (browser session) will have its own Singleton Object?

Comment: All objects in PHP (singleton or otherwise) exist __only__ for the duration of the request unless you explicitly maintain them in some form of permanent storage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singleton is design pattern and basically means:

- Make sure there can be only one instance of a class at any time.
- Provide global access to that single instance from anywhere within
  your application.

Example of singleton in PHP:

```
class Singleton
{
    protected static $instance = null;
    protected function __construct()
    {

     }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(static::$instance)) {
            static::$instance = new static;
        }
        return static::$instance;
    }
}
```

Surprise you don't need Singleton In PHP ,Here's why?

**Link of gordon blog why its of no use in PHP**: **http://blog.gordon-oheim.biz/2011-01-17-Why-Singletons-have-no-use-in-PHP/**

Answer (score 0):

I think that each client can have an instance of the object, but just one.

[check this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

A singleton object is a single instance of a particular class. In each PHP request this instance will be made, it's not even per session but really per request a person makes on your system.

For more knowledge check out the wikipedia page, also on how to create the pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 0):

PHP Sessions do not share data natively, so Singleton simply ensures, that you use one and only one object instance inside your Session, which is quite handy for Configuration, Database connection, cache objects for example.

There are several ways to achieve that. First one, is using static method. While it is very simple it promotes tight coupling and is very hard to unit test, which becomes a major concern when your project grows larger. Second one is simply saving an object inside some container property, and passing that container along through all the methods that depend on your singleton instance. It is harder at first, and there are many ways to achieve that, most common being the multitude of Dependency Injection methods.

Answer (score -1):

If you come from the Java land than you might have the impression that a singleton is a single instance on the whole webserver.

In PHP, whenever a new request comes to the server, PHP runs all the code and creates new objects and instances so unlike Java, in PHP, the singleton will be the only instance in the request context, not the server.

I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: Singleton has little to do with the programming language or server environment. It's a very general (and very limiting!) design pattern. See the accepted answer what I had in mind.

Comment: This was the accepted answer for a while. And the singleton implementation in Java and PHP are indeed very different.

Comment: You still can have singleton in the same sense in PHP and Java, it depends on the scope.

Comment: While it is possible to achieve this, this will not be the "natural way" to do this. To cite the first comment to this question: "All objects in PHP (singleton or otherwise) exist only for the duration of the request unless you explicitly maintain them in some form of permanent storage" - that's exactly the point I wanted to emphasize with this answer since the OP seemed to have trouble understanding exactly this aspect: "is it a one object for all the clients, or every client (browser session) will have it's own Singelton object?".